# AngularJS: Adding a module dynamically or after bootstrap / extending an exising module

Tags: angularjs, webpack

Lets say we have an angularjs application that is modularized and looks something like this:

```
let mod = angular.module('portal', [
   'ui.router',
   'portal.module1', 
   'portal.module2', 
   'portal.module3',
   'portal.module4'
])
```

And in the index template, we init the app the usual way with

```
<body ng-app="portal">
```

This is kind of our "core" functionality, which I would like to keep untouched. When creating new features for new clients, each one wants something a bit different, so we are trying to write new separate modules for each client and keep the core features untouched. The new modules do however rely on services and directives in the core features. Each new feature is a little microservice for the backend routes and then the new angularjs code for the UI.

If I create a new module, say `crazy_feature`, how can I get that module into the main `portal` angular application without touching the definition above? We are using webpack to bundle everything also.

Comment: Add the `crazy_feature` module as a dependency in one of the dependent modules, e.g. `angular.module("portal.module1",["crazy_feature"])`

Comment: yeah thats basically what I'm doing now, but the core stuff in each one of those modules is shared across multiple deployments, and each client gets custom stuff added on, so trying to keep the core "pure", if that makes any sense

Comment: What you have as a result - one site/page or one site/page per client?

Comment: each client gets their own deployment, totally separated infrastructure. The "core" repo gets forked and the customization happens in extra docker containers for the backend services

Comment: One thing to look into is [decorators](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators#what-are-decorators-). In AngularJS, decorators are functions that allow a service, directive or filter to be modified prior to its usage. Though I am skeptical. Their main use is to monkey patch 3rd party libraries.